# SSH to remote server and read Files in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, ssh

I just need to know whether below scenario is possible or not in Spring boot?

Assume I need to ssh to server and do operations in a specific directory in springboot. For example I just need to read file in Home directory in server 192.xxx.xxx.xxx in spring boot application. If this is possible how to set server credential(loging user,password) in application.properties.

Need you kind attention. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Just to make things clear, you want your Spring Boot application to SSH into a remote host and read a file from there?

Comment: yes. exactly.  is is possible?

Comment: Why won't you just use a fileserver on that location and use a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

There is a library called JSch - Java Secure Channel (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

This is how you connect to remote host:

```
private static final String REMOTE_HOST = "0.0.0.0";
private static final String USERNAME = "";
private static final String PASSWORD = "";
private static final int REMOTE_PORT = 22;
private static final int SESSION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
private static final int CHANNEL_TIMEOUT = 5000;

private void readFile() {
    String remoteFile = "/your/path/file.txt";
    Session jschSession = null;

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        jschSession = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT);

        jschSession.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        jschSession.connect(SESSION_TIMEOUT);

        Channel sftp = jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
        sftp.connect(CHANNEL_TIMEOUT);
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) sftp;

        InputStream stream = channelSftp.get(remoteFile);
        
        //Parsing your file or etc. here

        channelSftp.exit();

    } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (jschSession != null) {
            jschSession.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

As for how to set credentials from application.properties, you can use annotation:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail")
public class ConfigProperties {
    
    private String hostName;
    private int port;
    private String from;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

Example in your application.properties:

```
mail.hostname=host@mail.com
mail.port=9000
mail.from=mailer@mail.com
```

Further explanation can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot.

I hope it helps.